# Fedora 20: "Could not resolve host: download.fedoraproject.org"

Tags: fedora

I freshly installed Fedora 20 and the internet connection (ping, web browser) is working. However, when I try `yum update` I get the following error message:

```
failure: repodata/repomd.xml from download.fedoraproject.org_pub_fedora_linux_updates_testing_20_i386_: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/updates/testing/20/i386/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: download.fedoraproject.org"
```

Additional information:

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Fedora release 20 (Heisenbug)
Kernel \r on an \m (\l)

$ ls /etc/yum.repos.d/
download.fedoraproject.org_pub_fedora_linux_updates_testing_20_i386_.repo
fedora.repo
fedora-updates.repo
fedora-updates-testing.repo
fedora-updates-testing.repo~
rpmfusion-free-rawhide.repo
rpmfusion-free.repo
rpmfusion-free-updates.repo
rpmfusion-free-updates-testing.repo
rpmfusion-nonfree-rawhide.repo
rpmfusion-nonfree.repo
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates.repo
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-testing.repo
```

I also tried  (maybe it's helpful):

```
# yum-config-manager --disable rpmfusion-free-source
Loaded plugins: langpacks
=============================== repo: rpmfusion-free-source ===============================
[rpmfusion-free-source]
async = True
bandwidth = 0
base_persistdir = /var/lib/yum/repos/x86_64/20
baseurl = 
cache = 0
cachedir = /var/cache/yum/x86_64/20/rpmfusion-free-source
check_config_file_age = True
cost = 1000
deltarpm_metadata_percentage = 100
deltarpm_percentage = 
enabled = False
enablegroups = True
exclude = 
failovermethod = priority
gpgcadir = /var/lib/yum/repos/x86_64/20/rpmfusion-free-source/gpgcadir
gpgcakey = 
gpgcheck = True
gpgdir = /var/lib/yum/repos/x86_64/20/rpmfusion-free-source/gpgdir
gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmfusion-free-fedora-20
hdrdir = /var/cache/yum/x86_64/20/rpmfusion-free-source/headers
http_caching = all
includepkgs = 
ip_resolve = 
keepalive = True
keepcache = False
mddownloadpolicy = sqlite
mdpolicy = group:small
mediaid = 
metadata_expire = 604800
metadata_expire_filter = read-only:present
metalink = 
minrate = 0
mirrorlist = http://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/mirrorlist?repo=free-fedora-source-20&arch=x86_64
mirrorlist_expire = 86400
name = RPM Fusion for Fedora 20 - Free - Source
old_base_cache_dir = 
password = 
persistdir = /var/lib/yum/repos/x86_64/20/rpmfusion-free-source
pkgdir = /var/cache/yum/x86_64/20/rpmfusion-free-source/packages
proxy = False
proxy_dict = 
proxy_password = 
proxy_username = 
repo_gpgcheck = False
retries = 10
skip_if_unavailable = False
ssl_check_cert_permissions = True
sslcacert = 
sslclientcert = 
sslclientkey = 
sslverify = True
throttle = 0
timeout = 30.0
ui_id = rpmfusion-free-source/20/x86_64
ui_repoid_vars = releasever,
   basearch
username =
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't know why you rolled back my edit. I had improved the formatting, making your question clearer. I have now at least fixed the grammatical errors you had reintroduced but I suggest you consider incorporating some of my previous format changes as well.

Comment: terdon, oh, sorry, i didn't rollback on purpose. Maybe it happened when i refreshed the page... Can you undo it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site seems to be down right now.

What you can do as a temporary measure is to make an entry in your `/etc/hosts` file:

```
137.226.34.42 download.fedoraproject.org
```

then upgrade your system, comment out the above entry and reboot, to see if the problems have disappeared with the upgrade.

`137.226.34.42` is `ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de`.

Comment: Great, thanks for the quick answer!
I edited my /etc/hosts file like you recommended but i still get the same error message:
failure: repodata/repomd.xml from download.fedoraproject.org_pub_fedora_linux_updates_testing_20_i386_: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/updates/testing/20/i386/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 302 - Found

Comment: @StandardNerd Actually that url redirected somewhere else and I gave you the original IP address. I updated the answer, sorry for that.

Comment: strange that doesn't fix this error either. I tried  yum-config-manager --save --setopt=rpmfusion-free.skip_if_unavailable=true
and now i got Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: rpmfusion-free/20/x86_64
what's strange because i use the 32bit version...

Comment: The site is up fine for me. It may be a regional issue.